# Is there a way to show the browser's window properites that is set by application?

Tags: browser, window, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome dev tools:

Does anyone know how to see the window's properties that is set by current application?

Comment: Type `window` in the console.

Comment: Yeah, But it returns whole window properties. My need is to see the properties only set by current application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the nearest thing you can get is

```
Object.keys(window);
```

This actually lists a couple of "original" properties like `document` or `chrome`, but in Chrome 28 dev there are only 8 of those, and the others can be considered set by the application.